# How to trigger Child's touch event only when touched on a child view area. In other scenarios, parent's touch event needs to be triggered

Tags: android, touch

I have a custom relative layout that handles touch event to rotate this layout. The custom relative layout (parent) has an image view and frame layout as it's children. The frame layout in turn has a relative layout (not custom) which in turn has a number of image buttons. The image buttons can be considered as children in this case.

I have onTouch listener for each image button.  I have overridden the onInterceptTouchEvent in custom relative layout to return true so that child's touch event is not triggered when I rotate the custom parent layout. But when I tap or touch on the image buttons doesn't trigger the touch event of image button. If I return false from onInterceptTouchEvent in parent layout, the child's onTouch listener gets triggered and causes a rotation of the button, which I don't want.

How do I handle or dispatch touch events of the parent to its own onTouchEvent except the case where image button is clicked or touched, and the image button touch action takes effect without calling parent's touch event?

Comment: what api level are you using?

Comment: @pskink: Using API level 14.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by registering a `onTouchListener` for the child `ImageButton`. Then, inside the listener, get reference to the parent to stop the event from bubbling up by calling `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` on the parent view. Something similar to the snippet below...

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Notice this needs to happen for the whole duration of the touch event(s) and that this request sent to the parent needs to be switched back off so it can carry on intercepting touch events after the `ImageButton` touch event(s) has completed handling...it could be a long press touch event, so as soon as as the `ImageButton` detects the `ACTION_UP` motion event it should give back control to the parent

Comment: If I intercept the touch event in the parent view (meaning returning true from onInterceptTouchEvent), the touch event does not even come to the child view!

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing because this has worked for me like a charm. That is called event theft (or event bubbling in other platforms) and the event should come happen in the child view first if you are properly setting the onTouch listener, actually, make sure you return false, from the child view

Comment: Actually, this article which is less than a year old explains exactly the same...http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/prevent-touch-event-theft-in-android/